# How to catch 401 Unauthorized from SignalR after token expired

Tags: javascript, vue.js, azure-functions, signalr, signalr.client

I have built an page that gets real-time data from my azure functions backend via SignalR. Lets say i stay on the page, watching the data for 1 hour, and i might get a disconnect, the signalr client will try to reconnect automatically, this works fine. But when it tries to reconnect the jwt token might have expired and a 401 is throw from the signalr client.

Is there any way to catch this 401 from the signalr client when a reconnect is fired?

Many people seems to use .onclose() but will not work for me, or fetching a new jwt token every time they connect, i guess this might be the way i need to proceed, but i prefer if it would be possible to catch it instead, that would be a better fix in my opinion.

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
                .withUrl(config.default.hostname + "/api/v1/core/signalr",
                    { accessTokenFactory: () => store.state.accessToken })
                .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 0, 10000])
                .build();

connection.start();
```

Hope you understand what I'm looking for here!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

That is why on the `{ accessTokenFactory: () => store.state.accessToken }` you should pass a function that will refresh the token. So when the token expires, it will automatically check for new token from this method. So don't store the token in `store.state.accessToken`...

Comment: Ah okey, so there is no way to catch it then? i guess i will go with this solution then, thanks!

Comment: You can catch the error on the connect token like this `await this.hubMessageConnection.start()
      .then(() => {
        // Register application
        this.registerApplication();
      }).catch(() => {
        this.signalRError.emit(WidgetStateEnum.connectError);
      });` and emit the error event. On the handler for that event you can check if it is becuase of the token and call again the connect method.

Comment: FYI when using the access token factory, you will have to manually stop and then start the connection for the access token to be set again. If a client connects and their token expires while connected to the hub, it is not refreshed automatically. The need to stop and start the connection is caused by the WebSocket transport having to be closed and then started in order to change the access token query string. I simply have a timer on my client side that refreshes the access token, and then restarts the signalR connection so that the new token is used.

Comment: @Hedgybeats that is not true. I get the token from the angular oauth factory and don't need to refresh the token.

Comment: @Kiril1512 What is this.registerApplication(); in your scenario? also what is WidgetStateEnum.connectError? your own created Enum?

Comment: this.registerApplication() is a custom method that sends data to be added to signalr groups in the server. For example, clientId and tenant id, so I can create tenant groups. The WidgetStateEnum.connectError is a custom enum too...